# GCP Cloud Functions: Allow preflight request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cors, fetch-api, google-iam

I have a Cloud Function deployed in my GCP project. This Function uses GCP authentication to restrict access (so no unauthenticated user can call the function). When I'm trying to use `fetch()` from my browser to call this function, the browser first tries to send a `preflight request`, which omits the `Authorization` header.

I implemented CORS into my application with the help of [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-cors) tutorial, but the preflight request never actually reaches this part of the code, since unauthenticated users can't reach the function. An obvious solution would be to allow any unauthenticated user to call the function and handle authentication from the function itself, but that would be added complexity, that I'd like to avoid.

Is there any way to let `OPTIONS` requests through, while keeping other request methods back?

Here's the code I used for setting the CORS headers:

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  }
```

Comment: Please include the code you wrote. Links break, change, become outdated, etc. Are you setting this header `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization'`?

Comment: Consider using a custom domain (Firebase, load balancer, Cloud Run) so that CORS is not required.

Comment: my code is irrelevant because it isn't reached. I don't see the access control headers, because the code setting it isn't reached. The reason is that preflight requests don't include the authorization header, so the cloud function just rejects it outright.

Comment: temporarily I allowed unauthenticated users to reach the function, and now preflight requests work, but it also means that anyone can call my function, which isn't what I want

Comment: I'd like to add that I use the Cloud Function 2 (is what It's called I believe), and afaik under the hood it uses Cloud Run, but I'm not 100% sure how it works exactly

Comment: IAP, which handles authentication, has CORS disabled. Consult this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing#allowing_http_options_requests_cors_preflight) for more information.

Comment: thank you for the tip, and for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Hanley links to in the comments to the original question, you can [customise IAP settings to allow http options requests](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing#allowing_http_options_requests_cors_preflight). However, in order to do this you will need to enable IAP on your project and this means that all requests to your cloud functions will need to be signed.

An alternative option is to change the invoke permissions on each of your cloud functions to give "allUsers" the role "cloudfunctions.invoker".

You can do this manually within the GCP console:
https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list

Or you can do it in the terminal with

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION_NAME --member="allUsers" --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" --region="YOUR_REGION(e.g. us-east1)"
```

If you give allUsers invoke permission then you are letting anyone on the web call your cloud function so you will need to add appropriate authentication and security within your functions, such as adding suitable CORS checking.